# How to beat 'The memberInfo argument must be for class Game, but was for class BaseEntity. (Parameter 'memberInfo')'?

Tags: c#, mongodb, mapping, bson

I'm developping a web store (pet project) from scratch with sql server as a databse. I performed code first approach using EF core. But then I received a task where I need to use MongoDb as a second source of data. MongoDb already has some data and I'm allowed to perform only Read operations on it. So I came up with an idea to make a decorators for my existed repositories that would concat data from sql and mongo databases. I wrote `BsonClassMap` rules for every entity but here is an issue: every entity is derived from BaseEntity class

```
public abstract class BaseEntity
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    //...
}
```

and for example some derived entities

```
public class Game : BaseEntity
{
    public string Key { get; set; }
    //..
}


public class OrderDetail : BaseEntity
{
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    public string GameId { get; set; }
    public Game Game { get; set; }
    public string OrderId { get; set; }
    public Order Order { get; set; }
}
```

And look how it stored in mongo
Here is one record from product collection (Product is analogue of Game in sql database)
[I'm afraid I can't embed pictures in the post due to small reputation but still, you can take a look on it by this link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oohgy.png)
and one record from supplier collection:
[take a look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jrJBS.png)

You can see that both `product` and `supplier` has an `_id` field but it is meaningless because **SupplierID field in the product corresponds to SupplierID (not _id) field in the supplier** therefore I going to map SupplierId to the Id field of corresponding supplier c# class, and ProductID to Id field in c# Game class. [for better understanding - illustration of how items from product collection supposed to map on Game entity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WAb2V.png)

Here is BsonClassMap for type Game

```
public class GameMapConfiguration : IBsonClassMapConfiguration
{
    public void Register()
    {
        if (!BsonClassMap.IsClassMapRegistered(typeof(Game)))
        {
            BsonClassMap.RegisterClassMap<Game>(cm =>
            {
                cm.AutoMap();
                cm.SetIgnoreExtraElements(true);
                cm.MapMember(x => x.Id).SetElementName("ProductID").SetSerializer(new StringSerializerFromInt());
                cm.MapMember(x => x.Name).SetElementName("ProductName");
                cm.MapMember(x => x.Description).SetElementName("QuantityPerUnit");
                cm.MapMember(x => x.SupplierId).SetElementName("SupplierID")
                    .SetSerializer(new StringSerializerFromInt());
                //...
            });
        }
    }
}
```

But it throws an exception

> System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: 'The memberInfo argument must be
> for class Game, but was for class BaseEntity. (Parameter
> 'memberInfo')'

I can't specify how Id maps in BsonClassMap for BaseEntity because [Id has different element names in different collections. Click to see illustration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0HukW.png)

How can I play around here without changing models? is it actually possible?

Answer (score 0):

You could register a separate mapping for the base class. It is really strange that you have to do that, though. I use AutoMapper for mapping and haven't seen a quirk like this. This quirk kind of defeats the point of inheritance and seems like a bug in the utility.

```
BsonClassMap.RegisterClassMap<BaseEntity>(cm => {
    cm.AutoMap();
    cm.SetIgnoreExtraElements(true);
    cm.MapMember(x => x.Id).SetElementName("ProductID").SetSerializer(new StringSerializerFromInt());
    //...
});
```

Comment: As I said, I can't register it in the base class, because element name for Id propery in Product is "ProductID", in category - "CategoryID", order - "OrderID" etc.

Comment: Have you tried it?

Comment: It won't work for collections other than products

Comment: I decided to create new models and fetch data from mongo in them and then just map it to domain models with automapper

Answer (score 0):

this works for me:

```
  public class BaseEntity
{    
    public virtual string Id { get; set; }
    //...
}

public class Game : BaseEntity
{
    public override string Key { get; set; }
    //..
}

BsonClassMap.RegisterClassMap<BaseEntity>(cm => {
    cm.AutoMap();
    cm.SetIgnoreExtraElements(true);
    cm.MapProperty(nameof(Game.Key)).SetElementName("ProductID").SetSerializer(new StringSerializerFromInt());
    //...
});
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).